# Link same Microdata domain without nesting

Tags: html, microdata

I want to link the same Microdata domain in an other div, here is what I have:

```
<div id="colleau" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <!-- Here i got name, foundingDate, founders, etc... -->
</div>
```

But I have the phone number and the address in an other div and it's not linking:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="colleau">
  <!-- Phone, adress here -->
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one `div` gets the `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"` + `itemref`. The other `div` only gets the `id`.

```html
<div itemref="colleau" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
</div>

<div id="colleau">
  <!-- 'itemprop' in here will be added to the Organization -->
</div>
```